# find the limits : $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lfloor \frac{an+b}{cn+d}\rfloor=? $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

For $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$, determine
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left \lfloor \frac{an+b}{cn+d}\right\rfloor $$
Is there a general answer?

---

$\lfloor \rfloor = \text{floor function}$

Comment: $\frac{an+bn}{cn+dn}=\frac{a+b}{c+d}$?

Comment: Perhaps you get a cooler question by substituting $bn$ by $b$ and $dn$ by $d$.

Comment: @madprob hahahh

Comment: @EclipseSun I edited

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Rewrite the expression as

$$\left\lfloor \frac{a+\frac{b}n}{c+\frac{d}n}\right\rfloor$$

As $n\to\infty$, $b/n$ and $d/n$ approach $0$. Now, what are the points of discontinuity of $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$?

---

EDIT: In fact, as Daniel pointed out below, there is an even better expression:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{a}c+\frac{bc-ad}{c(cn+d)} \right\rfloor$$

As $n\to\infty$, the fraction $\frac{bc-ad}{c(cn+d)}$ approaches $0$. This form should make the behavior of the limit clearer in the cases where $a/c$ is at a point of discontinuity of $f$.

Comment: It might help even more to rewrite the expression as $\left \lfloor \frac{a}{c} + \frac{bc-ad}{c(cn+d)} \right \rfloor$ so if $\frac{a}{c}$ is at one of the points of discontinuity of $f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$, you know whether the argument is approaching it from below or above.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yep, that's great! Will add it onto the post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a direct answer :
if ${b \over d}>={a \over c}$ and $c\ne0$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left \lfloor \frac{an+b}{cn+d}\right\rfloor 
= \left \lfloor{a\over c} \right \rfloor
$$
if ${b \over d}<{a \over c}$ and $c\ne0$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left \lfloor \frac{an+b}{cn+d}\right\rfloor 
= \left \lfloor{a\over c} \right \rfloor-1
$$
if $c=0$ and $a>0$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left \lfloor \frac{an+b}{cn+d}\right\rfloor 
=\infty
$$
if $c=0$ and $a<0$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left \lfloor \frac{an+b}{cn+d}\right\rfloor 
=-\infty
$$
if $c=0$ and $a=0$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left \lfloor \frac{an+b}{cn+d}\right\rfloor 
=\left \lfloor{b \over d} \right \rfloor
$$

Comment: Not necessarily. Suppose a=c=1, b=-1, d=0. Then a/c=1 but the expression = [(n-1)/n] = 0.

Comment: $\lfloor \rfloor = \text{floor function}$

Comment: I think it should be: assume $c > 0$.  If $a/c \in \mathbb{Z}$ the answer is as above; if $a/c \notin \mathbb{Z}$, then the limit is $a/c$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler How can the limit be $a/c$ when $a/c\not\in\mathbb{Z}$, when every term of the sequence is an integer?

Comment: Oh, right, how silly of me - if $a/c \notin \mathbb{Z}$ then the limit is $\lfloor a/c \rfloor$.

Comment: Actually, in the case of $c > 0$ and $a/c \in \mathbb{Z}$, I think the distinction between $\lfloor a/c \rfloor$ and $\lfloor a/c \rfloor - 1$ cases should be based on whether $b/d \ge a/c$ or $b/d < a/c$.

Comment: It not depend. Simply make a experiment. a=3. c=5. b=9. d=2. If you put n=10000. Then will have $$\left \lfloor{30000+9}\over{50000+2}\right \rfloor = 0$$. a/c not depend on b/d

Comment: @DanielPol I think you missed the part that this is for the case $a/c \in \mathbb{Z}$.  For example, if $a=4$, $b=3$, $c=2$, $d=2$, then for $n=10000$, $\lfloor \frac{40003}{20002} \rfloor = 1 = \lfloor a/c \rfloor - 1$ even though $b \ge d$.

Comment: You are right. I need to rethink it in more detail. But later. Now i need to do something.

Comment: I already correct it. What you think now ?